# GBDK MetaTile Confusion

Tags: c, gameboy

I am trying to write my own Game Boy game using GBDK, and I am at a total roadblock.

The tiles can only be 8x8 or 8x16, but I need my sprites to be 16x16. From the extremely few things on the internet about it I picked up that I need to use metatiles. Only problem is I have NO clue how to use metatiles. The program I was using to make the regular tiles has an option to convert to metatiles, and that outputs this:

```
unsigned char TileLabelIndex[] = {
    1,
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03
};
/* Start of tile array. */
unsigned char TileLabel[] = {
    0x0F,0x0F,0x30,0x30,0x60,0x60,0x40,0x40,
    0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,
    0x40,0x40,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x30,0x30,
    0x10,0x10,0x0C,0x0C,0x06,0x06,0x03,0x03,
    0xF8,0xF8,0x44,0x44,0x06,0x06,0x02,0x02,
    0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,
    0x04,0x04,0x04,0x04,0x0C,0x0C,0x08,0x08,
    0x18,0x18,0x20,0x20,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0x80
};
```

Normally it would just be the part below `/* Start of tile array. */` and I could use it by doing:

```
set_sprite_data(0, 1, TileLabel);
```

But with metatiles if I do that it only gives me a quarter of the whole sprite.

Comment: I'm not familiar with metatiles themselves, but you can always use multiple sprites.  Also, you might want to use [SPRITES_8x16](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/doc/html/gb.h.html#a51), which simplifies this process.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Kind of, I ended up using 4 8x8 sprites.